# Jest mocking module implementation with .mockImplemetation

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, commonjs

Can anyone help here. I am really frustrated with how the `mockImplementation` works.
So, first of all I am using jest for node testing. I am using the commonjs modules. what I wanna do is that I am trying to mock a module using mockImplementation() and change its implementation between different tests according to this documentation here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-docs-en-mock-function-api-mockfnmockimplementationfn-or-mockimplementationonce-docs-en-mock-function-api-mockfnmockimplementationoncefn.

My code look like this:

```
const exportBigQueryTableModule =require('../repository/exportBigQueryTable')

jest.mock('../repository/exportBigQueryTable')

  describe('deleting files on table export fail', () => {
      mockExportBigQueryTable = jest
        .fn(() => Promise.resolve())
        .mockResolvedValueOnce()
        .mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('Could not export table'))

      exportBigQueryTableModule.mockImplementation(mockExportBigQueryTable)

      it(' should do some test', () => {})
  })
```

The problem here is that looks like that this line `jest.mock('../repository/exportBigQueryTable')` create for me a default mock  kind of `jest.fn()` and  the module is always loaded with that default function. So the mock function that I did provide on the test using the `mockImplementation` never overrides the previous one, I do not get what is the problem here. Why the same exmaple on the official documentation works the only difference is that it uses es6 modules on the doc sample.

I am not sure if  I am missing something here.

Comment: Can you please ad test sample to better understand what you are trying to achieve here!